# Pygame not updating dialogue within a sprite group

Tags: python, pygame

I have an issue with my dialogue index updating but not updating the text drawn to the screen. If the player is within distance of the npc the space button should update the dialogue. Currently it does draw the first index of dialogue if the player collides with the npc but moving away doesn't change anything as well as entering space. npc_list should be updating the self.image and then redrawing them.

[image]

---

```
    self.npcs = [ [[450,500,[]]],]
    self.npc_dialogue = [['Hi','Bye']]              
    self.npc_dialogue_sizes = [(25,50),(25,50)]              
    self.npc_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    #x,y,size,dialog,path_list
    for i,npc in enumerate(self.npcs[self.level]):
        new_npc = Npc((npc[0],npc[1]),self.npc_dialogue_sizes,self.npc_dialogue[0],npc[2])
        self.npc_list.add(new_npc)
```

---

```
 def display_stages(self,screen):
        clock   = pygame.time.Clock()
        running = True

        #Break if exit goes into a cutscene maybe use -1 and then update the level.
        dialog = False
        npc = None
        while running:
            if self.stages.level>=len(self.stages.exits) or self.state!=0:
                break
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    exit()
                keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  
                if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    if dialog and npc!=None:
                        #Update a single npc list dialogue
                        npc.update()
                        print('Update')

            screen.fill(white) 
            dialog, npc = self.npc_dialog()
                        
            if dialog and npc!=None:
                npc.draw_dialog(screen)
            
            self.stages.draw(screen) 
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(FPS)

def npc_dialog(self):
    for npc in self.stages.npc_list:
        gets_hit = npc.rect.colliderect(self.stages.player.rect)
        if gets_hit:
            return True, npc
    return False, None
```

---

```
 def draw(self,screen):
        if self.level < len(self.boundaries):
            screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
            self.npc_list.draw(screen)
```

---

```
class Npc(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,position,size,dialog,path_list):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        print(size,position,dialog)
        self.sizes = size
        self.image  = pygame.Surface(self.sizes[0])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = position
        self.path_list = path_list 
        
        # rework size and position to n*elements with dialog size
        positions = []
        for i in range(len(size)):
            positions.append(position)
        self.dialog = Dialog(positions,size,dialog)

    def update(self):
        #self.dialog.update()
        print(self.dialog.index,len(self.dialog.size))
        if self.dialog.index < len(self.dialog.size)-1:
            self.dialog.update()

    def draw_dialog(self,screen):
        print(self.dialog.dialog[self.dialog.index])

        if self.dialog.index < len(self.dialog.size)-1:
            print('Updating drawing')
            text = self.dialog.font.render(self.dialog.dialog[self.dialog.index], True, white)
            self.image.blit(text, (self.dialog.dialog_text_offset,self.dialog.dialog_text_offset))
```

---

```
class Dialog():
    def __init__(self,position,size,dialog):
        self.index = 0
        self.dialog = dialog
        self.sizes = size
        self.size = self.sizes[self.index]
        self.positions = position
        self.pos = position[self.index]
        self.image  = pygame.Surface(self.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.rect   = pygame.Rect((0,0), self.size)
        self.font   = pygame.font.Font(None,32)
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos
        self.dialog_background = (0, 0, 255, 127)
        self.dialog_text_offset = 5
        
    def update(self):    
        self.size   = self.sizes[self.index]
        self.pos    = self.positions[self.index]
        self.index  += 1
```

Comment: Way to much code, but likely `len(self.dialog.sizes)` instead of `len(self.dialog.size)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of size tuples is `self.dialog.sizes`, not `self.dialog.size`:

<s>`if self.dialog.index < len(self.dialog.size)-1:`</s>

```py
if self.dialog.index < len(self.dialog.sizes)-1:
```